# Meaning of $f(x, \cdot)$

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Let $(X,Σ, \mu)$ be a measure space and $(a,b)$ non empty open interval in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f:X \times (a,b) \to \mathbb{C}$ be a function and suppose that the integral $F(t) = \int f(x,t) dx$ is defined for every $t \in (a,b)$.

The **question** is:

> Using Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem how can we make the function $F(t)$ continuous?

This is the **proof**.

> Suppose for almost every $x \in X$ the function $f(x,\cdot)$ is continuous in $(a,b)$ and there is an integrable function $g:X \to [0,\infty)$ such that $|f(x,t)| \leq g(x)$ for every $t \in (a,b)$ and almost every $x \in X$. Then F is continuous in $(a,b)$.

I understand the proof but I do not understand the notation $f(x, \cdot)$. What does  $f(x, \cdot)$mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is given that $$f(\cdot, \cdot): X \times (a,b)\to \mathbb C$$ That is $f$ has two arguments, $x$ that takes values in $X$ and $t$ that takes values in $(a,b)$. Hence, if you fix $x$ in $X$ then $f(x, \cdot): (a,b) \to \mathbb C$ is a function of $t$.

Comment: Why cant we just write $f(t)$ instead of $f(x,.)$ for a function of t?

Comment: Because initially $f$ takes two arguments $x$ and $t$. For example: $f(x,t)=2x+t$ for all $x\in X$ and $t\in[a,b]$. Now *fix* $x\in X$ for example $x=1$ (just an example). Now $f(x=1, t)=2\cdot 1+t$ for all $t \in [a,b]$ or equivalently $f(x, \cdot)=2+\cdot$.

Comment: Out of interest in the context of the proof, why do we have to fix x? i.e why cant we say $f(x,t)$ is continuous in $(a,b)$?

Comment: To be precise: for (almost) any given $x$, the function $f(x,t)$ is continuous in $t$. This is the same statement as: for (almost) any given $x$, the function  $f(x,\cdot):[a,b]\to \mathbb C$ is continuous. Have seen in some textbooks, that for functions of one variable, they use the notation $f$ or $f(t)$ or $f(\cdot)$ to mean the same thing? This is now similar in two variables.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,\cdot)$ is the function $g:(a,b)\to\mathbb{C}$ given by $g(t)=f(x,t)$. Notice that $g$ depends on $x$. The notation $f(x,\cdot)$ makes this dependence explicit. This dependence is lost if you write $f(t)$; but $f_x(t)$ is ok. Indeed, W. Rudin uses $f_x$ instead of $f(x,\cdot)$ in his book *Real and Complex Analysis*.

The advantage of using $f(x,\cdot)$ is that we don't need make a new definition explicitly. If we want to use $f_x$ we have to define it explicitly (because it's not clear from the context what it is).

Example: if $f(x,y)=x+y$ then $f(5,\cdot)$ is the function $g(t)=5+t$.

Answer (score 1):

In this context for every fixed $x\in X$ we have a function $(a,b)\to\mathbb C$ that is prescribed by: $$t\mapsto f(x,t)$$

$f(x,\cdot)$  is a notation for this function.